# Google maps in China

Tags: cellphones, china

Using smartphone in China's cities,

how can I navigate by foot?

**Does anyone has a creative idea if I don't read or write chinese?**

Any recommended foot-navigation to China main cities?
(offline maps is preferable)

Comment: do you have an iPhone, Android or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying which smartphone you have. On iOS, an excellent app is MapsWithMe, which allows you to download maps per country and sometimes per province.
Major locations will be listed in English and Chinese, but lesser locations will probably only be listed in Chinese.

Comment: MapsWithMe is also available in Android

Answer (score 4):

Since last update, Google Maps (at least in Android) allow to put map areas available offline.

Here is a review of the update:
http://www.engadget.com/2012/06/27/google-maps-offline-android/

Comment: I was already possible before that. You just had to enable local caching and then view the map of your target location.

Comment: Now available in iOS too. Just type "Ok maps" in the search box and Google Maps will cache the current map area.